# Iterate over json object having an object

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following json output from an ajax call ,

```
{17: {access: "1",id: "2"}}
```

I'd like to iterate and get value of `id` , I am using below code but I get error of `undefined` in console .

```
$(obj).each(function(i, val) {
    console.log(val.id);
});
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Try debugging, start with `console.log(typeof obj)` and see what you get

Comment: @adeneo i get `object`  using `console.log(typeof obj)`

Comment: Great, now `console.log(val)` in the loop, and see why it doesn't have an `id` property

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
var obj = {17: {access: "1",id: "2"}} 

// Native JS
for (var k in obj) {
  console.log(obj[k].id)
}

// JQuery
// Documentaion: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/
$.each(obj, function(i, val) { 
  console.log(val.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Hope it helps, any questions?

As requested I'd like to point out that the term "JSON-Object" doesn't realy exist. You are using a simple JavaScript-Object, wich can be made of an JSON-String

Comment: Not if it is JSON, like it is described in the question.

Comment: JSON is a string, otherwise it is a Javascript object.

Comment: Some people call a whale is a big fish, but it's not.

Comment: Educate the OP as to the difference, point out that they have tagged the question as JSON. Seek clarification, be pedantic. Don't propagate incorrect terminology.

Comment: Probably too late, the OP has accepted an answer and fled the scene. :)

Comment: @Xotic750 he will see this (I added an Comment), and any future reader ofc ;) - It's a good answer now?

Comment: There was nothing technically wrong with your actual solutions, you gave both Javascript and jQuery, though I would probably guard with `hasOwnProperty` just because I'm anal like that. It was more a case of I have just read about 10 JSON tagged questions in the last hour, and none of them actually were about JSON. Your answer just happened to get my comment. ;)

Answer (score 2):

In this case you should use [$.each](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) from `jQuery` utils

```js
var obj = {17: {access: "1",id: "2"}} 

$.each(obj, function(i, val) {
    console.log(val.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @jimmy obonyo because `$( jQuery collection ).each(fn)` is an iterator that is used to iterate over only `jQuery` objects collection while `$.each(JS Object or Array, fn)`  is a general function for iterating over javascript objects and arrays.

Comment: @@jimmy obonyo look at this https://jsfiddle.net/fcf4tgut/ example that show the difference

Comment: @jimmy obonyo why have you changed your opinion and accepted another answer? If it is not useful for you why you accepted and then accepted other answer? If it is useful you had to not accept it - it is not game...

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `$.each(array, callback)`:

```js
var obj = {
  17: { id: "2", access: "1" },
  23: { id: "8" }
};

$.each(obj, function(i, val) {
  console.log(val.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.

```
var obj = {17: {access: "1",id: "2"}};

if( $.isPlainObject(obj) ) {
  $(obj).each(function(i, val) {
    console.log(val.id);
}); 
}
else {
  console.log('invalid Object');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) in a recursion style.

```js
var object = { 17: { access: "1", id: "2" } };

function find(p, o) {
    var result;
    Object.keys(o).some(function (k) {
        if (k === p) {
            result = o[k];
            return true;
        }
        if (typeof o[k] === 'object') {
            result = find(p, o[k]);
        }
    });
    return result;
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(find('id', object), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making an jQuery object of your JSON and then iterating over that jQuery object. Take a look at the API docs of [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/):

You are supposed to use it like this:

```
jQuery.each(object, callback)
```

Where `object` is the object to iterate over and `callback` is the callback function to be run for every key in `object`.

```js
var obj = {
  17: {
    access: "1",
    id: "2"
  },
  18: {
    access: "2",
    id: "5"
  }
};

$.each(obj, function(i, val) {
  document.body.innerHTML += val.id + "<br>";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```